# C++/Boost MPL: structure code likewise Haskell's let, where,

Tags: c++, haskell, boost, metaprogramming, boost-mpl

As C++ metaprogramming is functional: is there any way of doing something comparable to any functional programming language's (e.g. Haskell's) let or where construct?

I'm using Boost::MPL but would like to have more structure for longer metafunctions. Splitting into several functions is fine but I'd prefer let/where in some cases.

Comment: There comes a point where trying to shoehorn more template magic into C++ stops giving useful returns, especially when it comes to future compatibility and maintainance. Have you considered writing more code in a fast functional language which can generate libraries callable from C/C++? (OCaml springs to mind)

Comment: No, I have not considered that. I'm using meta programming because I need to do something at compile time, not because I want to write functional code. My pieces of code are not that complex. I just thought if I used the same function application three times in a 30-line-metafunction it would be nice to use some structure.

Comment: In C++11, you can do a lot of compile-time processing with `constexpr` instead of templates.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I fail to see how that will help. Do you have an example where `constexpr` makes meta-programming more structured and allows `let` and `where`?

Comment: constexpr allows more structured code as it is procedural, not functional. I use it in some cases if only numeric expressions should be evaluated. In those cases, I would not use template meta-programming because the code gets a lot less readable and the benefit of faster code is too small (the compiler should care about!). E.g., I'm using boost::type_traits - I would not get that functionality using constexpr. So, constexpr is fine but cannot replace template metaprogramming in all situations (those, I'm searching a solution for).

Comment: I'm completely clueless about C++, but `let x = y in z` is almost the same as `(\x. z) y`, so if anonymous functions are encodable maybe that's enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MPL itself doesn't support `let` clauses but some of the libraries built on top of it do. One example is [metamonad](http://abel.web.elte.hu/mpllibs/metamonad/manual.html). As the name suggests it also supports some other higher-level functional concepts (monads). A big drawback is, that `metamonad` is not an official part of the Boost distribution.

As far as work-arounds for the MPL go, splitting things into functions and using more namespaces to group them and then import the important symbol into your top-level namespace is probably your best choice.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that library. Seems to be what I've been searching for altough I do not know yet, if I'll use it. Extra library, looks like magic,...

Answer (score 1):

Boost.Phoenix has a construct called [let](http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/scope/let.html) that allows you to declare local variables in a higher order function context.  I think this is as high-level as it gets, though.  It's still runtime, not compile-time.

From the linked page:

```
let(_x = 1, _y = ", World")
[
    // _x here is an int: 1

    let(_x = "Hello") // hides the outer _x
    [
        cout << _x << _y // prints "Hello, World"
    ]
]
```

Comment: In my opinion, if you want to write functional code, you should take a functional language. I'm only search for a let-construct because template metaprogramming is functional.